# How can I insert html img?

Tags: html, image

I'm trying to put an image in my online curriculum from a website of my country.
The problem is, when I insert the following code:

```
<img src="//imageexemple.com/image.png">
```

The curriculum website, automatically, change my code to:

```
<img src="http://curriculumonline.com/imageexemple.com/image.png">
```

In other words, they are adding to my code the `http://curriculumonline.com/`text to prevent we import images out of their server.

I would like to know if there is any other way to try to insert the image from external website. I already tried "background-image: url" but doesnt work because they also remove the / when you use "background-image: url".

Comment: Is using a static image downloaded an option?

Comment: What is that "curriculum website"? Why not ask whoever maintains that site how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Use the full image source path, like

```
<img src="http://imageexemple.com/image.png">
```

Instead of

```
<img src="//imageexemple.com/image.png">
```

Comment: It doesn’t work, because the website is automatically adding to my code the http://curriculumonline.com/text to prevent we import images out of their server.